# Flutter: Error when trying to launch app after inserting new permissions package

Tags: android, flutter, permissions

I recently added this permissions package to my flutter app: https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler

Steps that I did:

1. Added the dependency to pubspec.yaml
2. Added the following to my android manifest:

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />`

   `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
3. I couldn't do the permission stuff for ios because from what I've read online, Android Studio on Windows can't emulate an ios device. I'm guessing I'll need to buy an Apple laptop to test the iphone version of my app.

The error (when running the app on a Pixel 2 API 30):

```
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone x86 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
C:\Users\UserABC\Documents\AndroidStudio\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.3.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionManager.java:321: error: cannot find symbol
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
                                                           ^
  symbol:   variable S
  location: class VERSION_CODES
C:\Users\UserABC\Documents\AndroidStudio\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.3.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:72: error: cannot find symbol
            case Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN:
                                    ^
  symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_SCAN
  location: class permission
C:\Users\UserABC\Documents\AndroidStudio\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.3.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:74: error: cannot find symbol
            case Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE:
                                    ^
  symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE
  location: class permission
C:\Users\UserABC\Documents\AndroidStudio\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.3.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
            case Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT:
                                    ^
  symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
  location: class permission
C:\Users\UserABC\Documents\AndroidStudio\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.3.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:259: error: cannot find symbol
                String result = determineBluetoothPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN);
                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_SCAN
  location: class permission
C:\Users\UserABC\Documents\AndroidStudio\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.3.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:270: error: cannot find symbol
                String result = determineBluetoothPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE);
                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE
  location: class permission
C:\Users\UserABC\Documents\AndroidStudio\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.3.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:281: error: cannot find symbol
                String result = determineBluetoothPermission(context, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT);
                                                                                         ^
  symbol:   variable BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
  location: class permission
C:\Users\UserABC\Documents\AndroidStudio\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\permission_handler-8.3.0\android\src\main\java\com\baseflow\permissionhandler\PermissionUtils.java:370: error: cannot find symbol
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S && hasPermissionInManifest(context, null, permission )) {
                                                        ^
  symbol:   variable S
  location: class VERSION_CODES
8 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':permission_handler:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: There is a similar issue on their github page, this will help you solve the issue - https://github.com/Baseflow/flutter-permission-handler/issues/748

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you were missing the configuration part of permission_hendler package. You will follow this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70926141/6344119) to figure-out your problem.